# CSS3 : inject a glyphicon icon in a button

Tags: html, css, glyphicons

In my Angular5 app , I have a datepicker library which is rendering a datepicker with some buttons

in those buttons , i want to inject some icons.

When inspecting the page ; the html structure would be something like this

```
<button>
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i>
<button>
```

**but as i'm not allowed to modify the html view** , i cannot add this icon directly in the html :

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i>
```

**The solution is to do it with css.**

Suggestions?

Comment: Yes you can do, which icon framework you using?

Comment: @Hanif : default one of angular5 : bootstrap 3.3.7

Comment: Set the icon as button background

Comment: @JoelBonetR  : since it s a bootstrap class , t wonder how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Glyphicon uses the pseudo classes `:before` & `:after` to inject the icons.

Use the `:after` pseudo class on this element and try adding the code of this specific icon. It should be something like this:

`.glyphicon.glyphicon-chevron-left:after{
content:"\e079";
}`

The content used in the code will vary. You can double check it in this [link](https://glyphicons.bootstrapcheatsheets.com/#) in "CSS rule". Also remember that you may want to style it properly to guarantee its visibility.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

By JS you can do this:

```
var elem = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
elem[0].innerHTML += "<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left'></i>";
```